# nginx windows 10 upstream timeout

Tags: nginx, docker, timeout

Short:

How can I setup an upstream timeout for nginx on windows?

Long:

I am currently on windows 10 and I have a nginx problem.
So the problem is that I want to have 2 different upstreams on my dev machine one pointing to an local running webserver and one to a docker container.

```
upstream api {
    server 127.0.0.1:9000;
    server 192.168.99.100:9000;
}

location /api {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_pass http://api;
        proxy_redirect off;
}
```

The error message:

> 2016/09/30 19:56:56 [error] 9836#11440: *154 upstream timed out
>   (10060: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did
>   not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection
>   failed because connected host has failed to respond) while connecting
>   to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "POST
>   /api/v1/demoText HTTP/1.1", upstream:
>   "http://127.0.0.1:9000/api/v1/demoText", host: "localhost:9091",
>   referrer: "http://localhost:9091/demo"

So it is quite obvious that nginx took the one which is not present and wait 1 min to time out. Under Mac OS X and Linux it worked as expected but not under windows.

I tried `proxy_read_timeout 1;` in the location part but without success

Answer (score 0):

i would check that you have actual connectivity between the docker container(e.g. 10.0.75.2) back to your host adapter on the windows side. On the windows side, the adapter should be called something like `vEthernet (DockerNAT)`.

Next, check the windows firewall (Windows Firewall with Advanced Security) to ensure you have the correct firewall set up there (there should be some default rules there).

Finally (and this seems to be reset every time docker has an update), see if changing the network category on the adapter. *This is probably best limited to a dev environment*. You can do this from powershell running as admin by running the following command:

`Set-NetConnectionProfile -InterfaceAlias "vEthernet (DockerNAT)" -NetworkCategory Private`